# Counting multiple touches using Cocos2dx 3.2

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, multitouch

I'm trying to count the number of active touches in screen in order to perform an an action in case that there are two touches:

```
auto jumpListener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
    jumpListener->onTouchesBegan = [=](const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event* event)
    {
        CCLOG("Multi-touch detected %d", touches.size());
        if(touches.size() == 2)
        {
            this->_player->jump();
        }

    };
```

But even if I'm touching with two fingers, I get that only 1 touch has been made, any suggestions?

Comment: Is Multi-Touch enabled? http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Enable_Multi-Touch

Comment: Forget that, I just read "android" in your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple and reliable is to use the singular event ["ccTouchBegan/ccTouchEnded"](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.3/df/de4/classcocos2d_1_1_layer.html#a4f573d111e347eed5da0cd69c4d269dc) events, instead of the multiple one "ccTouchesBegan/ccTouchesEnded".

Also, make sure you do this in a class that inherits from Layer/LayerColor, otherwise it won't work.

```
virtual bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *pTouch, cocos2d::Event *pEvent);

bool MySceneLayer::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *)
{
    // use location with 'pTouch->getLocationInView()'
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this method is for cocos2d-x 2.x

Comment: so basically increase a counter on touch began and reduce it on touch end?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Exactly.

Comment: ok, did that part, but scaling the sprite when original distance and current distance between two fingers makes everything black

Answer (score 0):

```
//.h
int touchCount = 0;

//.cpp
auto listener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
listener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan, this);
listener->onTouchesEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesEnded, this);


void HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
touchCount++;
CCLOG("Multi-touch detected %d", touchCount);

if (touchCount == 2){

CCLOG("two finger are on the screen");

  }

}

void HelloWorld::onTouchesEnded(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
touchCount--;
}
```

touchCount will keep track of how many touches are on the screen and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Sorry about that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

```
auto jumpListener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
listener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan, this);

void HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch *> &touches, cocos2d::Event * event)
{
CCLOG("MULTI TOUCH BEGAN");
}
```

Try this